# Convert Mantaflow or other sims to mesh/get specific frame from sim?

Tags: fluid-simulation, 3d-printing, ocean-simulation, mantaflow

Is there a way to convert simulations into mesh? Freeze on a specific frame you like, bake it/convert it to geometry so you can 3D print it? I'm asking specifically about water.

Comment: Export and Import which is a choice on the File Menu.  I have used OBJ format.  Fluid Simulation. You may try to apply modifier.